Запрет выполнения неподписанных jar файлов
Я использую jdk corretto 8.402 на Debian 12. Мне нужно запретить запуск jar файлов, которые не подписаны или подписаны сертификатом, издателем которого являюсь не я. Я нашёл, что для для этого используется утилита "jarsigner", но не совсем понимаю, как мне проверить jar на соответствие конкретно моей подписи, и как это делать в момент запуска любого jar файла.

на оракловской jre это делается через политику. читайте начиная с https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/receiver.html
вот тут ставят политику на разрешение https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/wstep3.html
потом добавьте политику на запрет всего остального
